# What is the optimal SVG viewBox size for web applications?

Tags: svg, web-applications, viewbox

**Background**

While creating [SVG](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG) icons for my web application, I noted that the two most common [`viewBox`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/viewBox) sizes others seem to design around are `0 0 20 20` (for solid icons) and `0 0 24 24` (for outline icons).

Ideally, I would like to like to standardize on one [`viewBox`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/viewBox) size for my app and am trying to understand any best practices that already exist.

Is there a currently or generally accepted 'best practice' sizing for the viewBox when creating SVGs for web applications?

Comment: One question at a time, please. [ask] Your question is also opinion and things we wouldn't know. [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: Thanks @Rob I have edited my question to ensure there's only one per your guidance. The update should also deal with your concern around this being an opinion based question, as it's now a binary one.

Comment: @robertLongson can you help me understand? 

Surely the answer is either "yes there is a standard, here are the references" or "no there isn't"? I'm not sure that leaves much room for opinion, but based on your answer it sounds like the answer is probably the latter?

Comment: OK, no there isn't then. Pick what works best for you i.e. use your own opinion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no best practice; the viewBox is **your** definition, the DOM element size will be the same

example: It is up to **you** if you draw in `viewBox="0 0 5 5"` or `viewBox="0 0 25 25"` *'accuracy'*

[image]